# Add InstallerListener to IzPack installer project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, installation, izpack

I have a working IzPack installer project set up with maven and added following to my install script **install.xml** to [`installation`][`listeners`]:

`<listener classname="`*`(company-name)`*`.listener.InstallerListener" stage="install"/>`

Sadly, the line seems to be ignored and the debugger does not halt on set breakpoints in the `InstallListener` class. I have read [the documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#what-you-have-to-do) for `InstallListener`s, but it is not useful as I have the build process integrated with maven; here are the relevant parts of the Project Object Model **pom.xml**:

```
<properties>
    <izpack-standalone.version>4.3.1</izpack-standalone.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- izpack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${izpack-standalone.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>    
    <!--  IzPack compiler  -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.izpack.izpack-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
                <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>${izpack-standalone.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <izpackBasedir>${staging.dir}</izpackBasedir>
            <customPanelDirectory>${staging.dir}</customPanelDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>standard-installer</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>izpack</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

What am I missing here?

---

**Note:** The compiled installer does contain the specified `InstallerListener` class file, so it is available at runtime.

Comment: The izpack-maven-plugin states for the customPanelDirectory: Location of external custom panel's jars which must be placed under sub directory bin/panels. ( ie ${customPanelDirectory/bin/panels ). Does that match your setup and the location of our InstallListener class file in the installer?

Comment: I build the panels along with the install script and wrap it all up to a jar with ant / maven-dependency-plugin.

Comment: So far so good. But is this jar file located in {customPanelDirectory}/bin/panels when creating the installer?

Comment: Our code is included to  the target installer jar with ``<jar src="${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>`` (**install.xml**)

Answer (score 1):

You must place the jar file containing your panel classes into the `{customPanelDirectory}/bin/panels` folder where it will be picked up automatically by the izpack-maven-plugin.

In the case above this folder would resolve to `{staging.dir}/bin/panels` since you configured `<customPanelDirectory>${staging.dir}</customPanelDirectory>`.

Adding it to install.xml file will not work, since this would be resolved at install time, but not at installer build time.

Comment: Where is ``${customPanelDirectory}``? And are you sure that all the code should be treated as a "panel"? Because it isn't just a panel. It has business logic and a bunch of panel classes.

Comment: ${customPanelDirectory} is what you defined in your plugin configuration: `<customPanelDirectory>${staging.dir}</customPanelDirectory>`. There you should place the jar containing all the needed classes.

Comment: When I changed the compilation target of our code to ``{staging.dir}/bin/panels`` (**pom.xml**) and removed ``<jar src="${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>`` (**install.xml**), the izpack compiler did *not* pick the "panel jar file" up. We found workarounds which makes the usage of a ``InstallerListener`` unnecessary. Nevertheless, I am still interested to know why it does not work.

Comment: It might be necessary to have the jar file here and not just the compiled classes, other than that I am out of ideas.